# Is the ::before selector unsupported when applied to HTML Emails?

Tags: html, css, email

Ok so this may be a silly question but I'm not currently finding any useful material online to find an answer to my rather simple but annoying problem.

I'm having a very annoying problem when attempting to style the bullet point before a list item within a html email.

All I want to do is turn the list item into a square and then colour the bullet point a certain colour but leave the list text content black. It should be as simple as the css below but it doesn't work.

`ul{list-style-type:square;}
ul li{color:#000;}
ul li::before{color:#fac600}`

I have also tried the following but believe ::before may be unsupported

```
  ul{list-style:none;}
  ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #fac600;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  }
```

Frustrated at this point I also tried to use an image to replace the bullet point, but this also doesn't work as I know this is unsupported.

I can achieve easily changing the bullet to a square and changing the colour of the bullet + the list text but not separately.

Anyone had this problem or know of a workaround?

Interested to hear your guys thoughts and wonder if you experienced the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in emails only inline property works

Comment: So from your answer there isn't an achievable work around for this I'm guessing? Short answer is it's unsupported?

Comment: yes, i work on HTML emails but it not support any extended file, only inline CSS works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default you are unable to change the colour of `li` bullets, regardless if you're developing for an email or not. However, you can use the following piece of css to essentially hide the original bullet point and then create a new one.

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  }
  
ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #fac600;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, 
Sorry I should have mentioned, I already tried this option also. However I think the ::before selector may be unsupported I just can't find a resource to confirm.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/using-pseudo-elements-to-progressively-enhance-your-emails/) , pseudo elements are supported in most email clients; however I never write for emails so can't confirm myself.

Comment: Hi Matt, me either generally. Anyway I gave this a go again and the bullet point actually ends up being stripped from the receiving email entirely. Annoying that it appears supported but actually doesn't work. Via the CMS im using with AcyMailing it works absolutely fine so I know the code is good. MailClient just doesn't like it lol

Comment: Yeah it seems like they have very limited support then. I found [this on MailChimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/) basically says that only AOL support pseudo elements.

Comment: Yeah Nisharg above was mentioning that only inline css elements were possible (which was my initial thought). Extended CSS appears to be unsupported. Like you I don't do many HTML emails but I do dabble from time to time. It's good to know for future reference. It's a very minor cosmetic change anyway. Thanks for your insight with this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Here is another great table of [what CSS is supported by whom](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/before/). (*campaignmonitor.com*)

Comment: Hi Amaury, this is a really handy resource. Will defo bookmark this for future reference, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

`:before` is not universally supported in email. It works with IOS, Apple, but does not work with Gmail or Outlook.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/before/